# Why aren't annotated methods having their names obfuscated

Tags: java, maven, proguard, obfuscation

I am a VERY new developer. I am currently making some Minecraft plugins that I plan on selling, and am currently trying to figure out how to obfuscate my work.

Right now I am having two issues:

1. Any methods that are annotated will not have their names obfuscated
2. @Override isn't showing up in the obfuscated code, is this a problem?

Proguard options (Maven):

```
                     <options>
                        <option>-dontnote module-info</option>
                        <option>-dontnote jdk.internal.jimage.*</option>
                        <option>-dontnote jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.*</option>
                        <option>-dontnote jdk.internal.jrtfs.*</option>
                        <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                            @org.bukkit.event.EventHandler *;
                            }
                        </option>
                        <option>-overloadaggressively</option>
                        <option>-repackageclasses</option>
                        <option>-keepdirectories</option>
                        <option>-keepattributes *Annotation*, Override</option>
                        <option>-keep, allowobfuscation public class me.mypackage.TestClass</option>
                    </options>
```

Comment: Kalamity clarified in a comment that the real question is "why aren't annotated methods having their names changed".  I have deleted my answer accordingly as it does not address that question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line to solve my issue, added allowobfuscation to this line

```
<option>-keepclassmembers, allowobfuscation class * {
    @org.bukkit.event.EventHandler *;
    }
</option>
```